# How can I change the search form placeholder value?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

How can I change the search form placeholder value? I can change the value of it in my **.theme** file, but I want it to be also translatable.

What is the correct way of doing this?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You don't alter a [`TranslatableMarkup`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21StringTranslation%21TranslatableMarkup.php/class/TranslatableMarkup/8.2.x) object: You replace it with another `TranslatableMarkup` object you obtain from `t('The new placeholder')`, `new TranslatableMarkup('The new placeholder')`, or a function/method that returns a `TranslatableMarkup` object.

```php
function mytheme_form_search_block_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form['keys']['#attributes']['title'] = t('The new placeholder');
}
```

The result of this code is the following (on Google Chrome running on OSX "El Capitan").

> [image: screenshot]

What you are showing is not the placeholder, but the input title. To change the placeholder of a form element, you should use code similar to the following one.

```php
function mytheme_form_search_block_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form['keys']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('The new placeholder');
}
```

Using this code, you get the following result.

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: 'keys' needing to be replaced with the id of the input element, eg $form['search_api_fulltext']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Mot clés');

Comment: *keys* is correct for the search form used by Drupal core.

Answer (score 2):

you can use form alter for this

```
 function yourtheme_form_search_block_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
      $form['keys']['#attributes']['placeholder'][] = t('enter the terms you wish to search for');
    }
```

Comment: @ Naveen Thanks for your contribution, In our case its not taking placeholder attributes, its working when I change $form['keys']['title'] = t('new place holder').

Comment: 'keys' needing to be replaced with the id of the input element, eg $form['search_api_fulltext']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Mot clés');

Answer (score 2):

I think, we could alter the form details from hook_form_FORM_ID_alter, The following code would help to fix the issue :)

```
function my_module_form_search_block_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form['keys']['#title'] = t('Your custom Title');
  $form['keys']['#attributes']['title'] = t('Your custom Placeholder');
}
```

The above code will change the title and placeholder for the search form.

Comment: 'keys' needing to be replaced with the id of the input element, eg $form['search_api_fulltext']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Mot clés');